# Fedora 34 lags when I play any video or audio

Tags: fedora, audio, video, lag

I dual booted windows and fedora 34. My windows works just fine when I play any video or audio but in fedora there is a lot of lag. Fedora works just fine when I don't play any video or audio. When I play a video in youtube the lag increases as I increase the resolution. I used ubuntu 20.04 also but there was no such lag and it worked just fine.
***Youtube Video lag.***

[image: Youtube video lag]
***Graphics feature status***. [image]
***Output of- dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn***

````
x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
[Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs within socket(s), fixing all errors
wait_for_initramfs() called before rootfs_initcalls
efifb: Ignoring BGRT: unexpected or invalid BMP data
usb: port power management may be unreliable
i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp
systemd-sysv-generator[510]: SysV service '/etc/rc.d/init.d/livesys' lacks a native systemd unit file. Automatically generating a unit file for compatibility. Please update package to include a native systemd unit file, in order to make it more safe and robust.
systemd-sysv-generator[510]: SysV service '/etc/rc.d/init.d/livesys-late' lacks a native systemd unit file. Automatically generating a unit file for compatibility. Please update package to include a native systemd unit file, in order to make it more safe and robust.
systemd-journald[531]: File /run/log/journal/a5ad4a29437f4f5da9d6971f7ca4b3d6/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
kauditd_printk_skb: 97 callbacks suppressed
iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: WRT: Overriding region id 0
iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: WRT: Overriding region id 1
iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: WRT: Overriding region id 2
iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: WRT: Overriding region id 3
iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: WRT: Overriding region id 4
iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: WRT: Overriding region id 6
iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: WRT: Overriding region id 8
iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: WRT: Overriding region id 9
iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: WRT: Overriding region id 10
iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: WRT: Overriding region id 11
iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: WRT: Overriding region id 15
iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: WRT: Overriding region id 16
iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: WRT: Overriding region id 18
iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: WRT: Overriding region id 19
iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: WRT: Overriding region id 20
iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: WRT: Overriding region id 21
iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: WRT: Overriding region id 28
thermal thermal_zone7: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
Bluetooth: hci0: MSFT filter_enable is already on
NOHZ tick-stop error: Non-RCU local softirq work is pending, handler #280!!!
NOHZ tick-stop error: Non-RCU local softirq work is pending, handler #280!!!
NOHZ tick-stop error: Non-RCU local softirq work is pending, handler #280!!!
NOHZ tick-stop error: Non-RCU local softirq work is pending, handler #280!!!
NOHZ tick-stop error: Non-RCU local softirq work is pending, handler #202!!!
NOHZ tick-stop error: Non-RCU local softirq work is pending, handler #202!!!
NOHZ tick-stop error: Non-RCU local softirq work is pending, handler #202!!!
NOHZ tick-stop error: Non-RCU local softirq work is pending, handler #280!!!
NOHZ tick-stop error: Non-RCU local softirq work is pending, handler #280!!!
NOHZ tick-stop error: Non-RCU local softirq work is pending, handler #82!!!```        
  
  
Output of sensors
  
  
```iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +44.0°C  

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:     1000 RPM

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:           7.85 V  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +57.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:        +58.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:        +58.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

nvme-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +42.9°C  (low  =  -5.2°C, high = +79.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +44.0°C  (crit = +75.0°C)```
````

Comment: Please edit your question and add the first section of `about:gpu` which is "Graphics Feature Status". If that's a Wayland session, please try using an X11 one.

Comment: yes I am using X11 only

Comment: Please post the output of `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn` and `sensors` while you're playing a video.

Comment: Please edit your post and add this information as **text**, not as pictures. Thank you. Please do not remove previously posted information. It could help others understand what's going on. From what I can see your system is not stable. I'm not sure why. Before getting `dmesg`, please reboot first.

Comment: `NOHZ tick-stop error: Non-RCU local softirq work is pending, handler` could be the reason. Are there any BIOS updates for your device? Could you install them?

Comment: I think its already updated